Why clicking header files would jump to different locations in VSCode?
I press Ctrl and click #include<stdio.h>, #include<bits/stdc++.h>, #include<stdbool.h> and so on, they all jump to different header files. For example:

#include<stdio.h> --> /usr/incldue/stdio.h
#include<stdbool.h> --> /usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/stdbool.h
#include<bits/stdc++.h> --> /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11/bits/stdc++.h

example:


Environment:

WSL Ubuntu22.04
VSCode
use gcc
clangd extension on (Default Configuration)
No project config in the working directory, it is just for some simple cpp files.

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

I tried set default header in cpp_c_cpp_properties.json or .clangd as below, but they all failed.
"includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**",   
            ],

It is a normal situation? It is my first time I write C++ in Linux. Usually I write C++ in Windows, I downloaded mingw-x64 and every time I click header files it all seemly jumped to the same location (all under the folder mingw).

"they all jump to different header files" -- Well, they are different header files, so this much should be expected. Is it rather the different directories that surprises you?

Side note #include<bits/stdc++.h> should not even be in your own code. It is not standard C++. And yes this is normal, the header files come from different libraries.

Yes, the paths look correct.

/usr/include is where most headers are installed. Apparently this includes libc (which is what owns stdio.h).

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11 contains the C++ standard library headers for libstdc++ v11.

/usr/lib/llvm-14/lib/clang/14.0.0/include/ is where Clang stores its own header overrides (for some reason they seem to want to have a custom stdbool.h instead of the libc one).


You should've had a similar directory structure in MinGW.
And lastly, if you're using Clangd, you don't need c_cpp_properties.json (it's for Microsoft's C/C++ plugin).

Thank you! But I just want to use GCC in this environment. So in this case, I must jump to some header files from the directory "Llvm-14"? And last, I find if I don't config c_cpp_properties.json, I wouldn't be able to use debug feature in vscode easily. (There is no project config in the working directory, it is just for some simple cpp files)

@Exisfar It shouldn't matter that Clangd prefers its own headers to GCC's, it only affects code completion. As for debugging, I think you only need launch.json.
